# 60s or 70s made-for TV sci-fi movie with brain washing and Japanese agents

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

Saw half of this very interesting movie as a kid, always remembered it, but never saw the ending!

A lot of the movie takes place in some government facility in the woods where some kind of agent with amnesia or something is recovering in bed and being questioned. Some kind of computer device near the bed feeds or displays information, and they activate the memory files by sticking into a slot what looks like circuit boards.

And something in the movie has to do with an underwater Japanese hi-tech base.

Anyway, I'd love to know what movie it was so I can see how it ended!

Answer (score 4):

All of this is exactly the movie "[Project X](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063465/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)" ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_X_(1968_film))) except for one thing. The antagonists are Chinese, not Japanese.

> A spy is brought back from cryogenic suspension after being almost killed in a plane crash returning from a mission to learn about a deadly new weapon being developed in the East. But the vital memories are being suppressed, so the authorities use ultra-advanced technologies to try to uncover the secret.

[This](http://www.starringthecomputer.com/feature.html?f=314) may be the computer device you're thinking of:

[image: Image of IBM AN/FSQ-7 in film]

The underwater base might be what is referred to by the Wikipedia quote of "Another scene that was animated was a reused shot from Jonny Quest where an underwater elevator terminates into a submarine on the ocean floor."